# Streaming dataflow takes 1-2 seconds to pass data between transformation

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to run the streaming dataflow with 2.0/1.0 versions ,
we have less than 100 millis SLA ,  and incoming message it is going through 
4 transformations.

1) first transformation is taken less than 10 millis.

2) second transformation is dealing with bigtablet and some sideinput less than 5 mb data  and takes the less than 30-40 millis.

3) the third transformation is important one->

> The third transformation has three side input 2 are less than 5 mb
>   and the third one contains the decision tree model files(77) which is around 127 mb.
>
> I am using the JPMML-Convertor library for prediction using decision tree model files which is for first time takes the 400 millis and on words takes 30-40 millis.
>
> To avoid the the first 400 millis I made a static variable and assign side input data to it, that solves the problem.

All processing logic in third transformation takes around 50 millis.

But the time taken for the messages to go from 2nd transformation(after emitting) to 4th transformation is around 1-2 sec.

I didn't understand what the problem is because I didn't see any warning or error messages in logs.

In dataflow UI If I select the third transformation , there I can see that the 2nd transformation already emitted the message but the 3rd transformation didnt receive that message.

May be it is preparing new instance because I see many logs that I printed in startBundle method for single method.

Some times I am seeing below warnings :

> Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: 7b:e5:7f:8a:22:9c:fc:6a

**I am using below configuration:**

> worker machine type : n1-standard-4
>
> workerCacheMemoryMB : 3072
>
> I tried both dataflow 1.x/2.x version.

Any suggestions on this will be very helpful.

please comment if you need any more details.

Thanks.

Comment: Are all of your transformations simple ParDo's, or do you have any windowing / triggering / grouping / combining going on? Also how did you measure the latency? Do you have a job ID?

Comment: All are simple ParDo's,To calculate the latency I have printed the two messages one is just before emitting element from 2nd transformation and other is in processElement of third transformation and taken the time difference from logs time.JobId : 2017-09-08_05_41_14-13713041610599796429

Comment: Hm, I looked up the definition of this job and it appears to be far from a simple chain of ParDo's. Do you have any particular ParDo's in that job in mind? If you'd prefer to give more details in a private forum you can use dataflow-feedback@google.com.

Comment: I have mailed the details with subject name same as above question, thanks.